# PHP redirect any url to root

Tags: php, url, redirect

I'd like to redirect to the root url if the url is not the root url. The following code results in a redirect loop.

```
if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] != "/") || ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] != ""))
{
    header('Location: /');
    die();
}
```

Despite researching, I can't get the following code to work properly.
What am I missing? (I'd like not having to adjust the .htaccess file.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] != 'your root url' ){
    header('Location: your root url');
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In subfolders you can use ../ to get one folder higher.

```
header("Location: ../"); exit;
```

If you have a flat folder structure this is an easy way to redirect to root

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll try.